# How to use fs module in NodeJS with async await?

Tags: node.js, fs

I'm trying to do a controller in nodeJS that search in a database some images and then it sends it to front end. The problem is I'm using `fs.promise` to open the images and save it to the object which will be sended to the frontend but it's sent before any image has been saved into object, the front_img, back_img, side_img are recived empty in frontend.

What's happening is that the response is sent before the code of fs starts and I'm using async await, this won't be happening.

Here is the code:

```js
routerProgress.get("/see-first-last-progress", async (req, res) => {
  let infFront = {
    last_progress: {},
    first_progress: {},
  };

  // Find last progress
  try {
    const single_progress = await Progress.findOne({
      where: { user_id: req.user.id },
      order: [["date", "DESC"]],
    });
    let obj = {
      weight: single_progress.dataValues.weight,
      // This is syncron, we have to do it async
      front_img: {},
      side_img: {},
      back_img: {},
      date: single_progress.dataValues.date,
    };
    // Check if data is the image or there's more information
    await fs.promises.readFile(`${path}${dirname}${single_progress.dataValues.front_id}`, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        res.send({ statusCode: "404", msg: "Photo not found" });
        return;
      } else {
        obj.front_img = data;
      }
    });
    await fs.promises.readFile(`${path}${dirname}${single_progress.dataValues.side_id}`, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        res.send({ statusCode: "404", msg: "Photo not found" });
        return;
      } else {
        obj.side_img = data;
      }
    });
    await fs.promises.readFile(`${path}${dirname}${single_progress.dataValues.back_id}`, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        res.send({ statusCode: "404", msg: "Photo not found" });
        return;
      } else {
        obj.back_img = data;
      }
    });
    obj.date = obj.date.toISOString().replace(/T/, " ").replace(/\..+/, "");
    infFront.last_progress = obj;
  } catch {
    res.send({
      statusCode: "500",
      msg: "An error occurred, please try again",
    });
    return;
  }

  // Find first progress
  try {
    const single_progress = await Progress.findOne({
      where: { user_id: req.user.id },
      order: [["date", "ASC"]],
    });
    let obj = {
      weight: single_progress.dataValues.weight,
      // This is syncron, we have to do it async
      front_img: {},
      side_img: {},
      back_img: {},
      date: single_progress.dataValues.date,
    };
    // Check if data is the image or there's more information
    await fs.promises.readFile(`${path}${dirname}${single_progress.dataValues.front_id}`, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        res.send({ statusCode: "404", msg: "Photo not found" });
        return;
      } else {
        obj.front_img = data;
      }
    });
    await fs.promises.readFile(`${path}${dirname}${single_progress.dataValues.side_id}`, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        res.send({ statusCode: "404", msg: "Photo not found" });
        return;
      } else {
        obj.side_img = data;
      }
    });
    await fs.promises.readFile(`${path}${dirname}${single_progress.dataValues.back_id}`, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        res.send({ statusCode: "404", msg: "Photo not found" });
        return;
      } else {
        obj.back_img = data;
      }
    });
    obj.date = obj.date.toISOString().replace(/T/, " ").replace(/\..+/, "");
    infFront.first_progress = obj;
  } catch {
    res.send({
      statusCode: "500",
      msg: "An error occurred, please try again",
    });
    return;
  }
  res.send({ statusCode: "200", data: infFront });
});
```

If anyone know how to fix it, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try it like this just try to add `new Promise(resolve, reject)` before `await`

```
  await new Promise(resolve, reject)=> {
fs.promises.readFile(`${path}${dirname}${single_progress.dataValues.front_id}`, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    res.send({ statusCode: "404", msg: "Photo not found" });
    return;
  } else {
    obj.front_img = data;
  }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since node v10.x you could use the native node code of fs-promise.
An excerpt from the docs:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const fsPromises = fs.promises;
```

Read more:
https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_access_path_mode

Answer (score 0):

When I check your code, I see you are mixing `callbacks` and `async/await` and thats the reason your expected o/p is not coming.

If you are on latest node version you can do that using:

```
const { readfile } = require('fs/promises');
```

Now, for every fileread replace that code with the below one:

```
  try {
      const res = await readFile(`${path}${dirname}${single_progress.dataValues.front_id}`)
      obj.front_img = res;
    } catch (error) {
      res.send({ statusCode: "404", msg: "Photo not found" , verboseMessage: `${error}`});
    }
```

I have multiple `readfile` statement almost they are reading file, you should replace them with a function like this:

```
const readingFile = async (path) => {
  try {
   const res = await readFile(`${path}${dirname}${single_progress.dataValues.front_id}`)
    return res;    
  } catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
 }
}


try {
  const single_progress = await Progress.findOne({
    where: { user_id: req.user.id },
    order: [["date", "DESC"]],
  });
  let obj = {
    weight: single_progress.dataValues.weight,
    // This is syncron, we have to do it async
    front_img: {},
    side_img: {},
    back_img: {},
    date: single_progress.dataValues.date,
  };
  // Check if data is the image or there's more information
  // this will be more readable and you can catch errors at one place.
  obj.front_img = await readingFile(`${path}${dirname}${single_progress.dataValues.front_id}`);
  obj.side_img = await readingFile(`${path}${dirname}${single_progress.dataValues.side_id}`);
  obj.back_img  = await readingFile(`${path}${dirname}${single_progress.dataValues.back_id}`);
  obj.date = obj.date.toISOString().replace(/T/, " ").replace(/\..+/, "");
  infFront.last_progress = obj;
} catch {
  res.send({
    statusCode: "500",
    msg: "An error occurred, please try again",
  });
  return;
}
```